# Relationship between geodesics and curvature lines on surfaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

I'm trying to understand the relationship between geodesics and lines of principal curvature (to keep things simple, let's say Riemannian 2-manifolds embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$).  In my reading, I came across the following discussion in Cartan, Riemannian Geometry in an Orthogonal Frame (pp. 231-232):

> 1. Parallel transport preserves the principal directions, the principal curvature, the asymptotic tangents and the geodesic curvatures.
> 2. Let $M$ and $M^\prime$ be two neighboring points of a curvature line.  Under parallel transport, the principal directions at the point $M$ are transferred into the principal directions at the point $M^\prime$.  Therefore, the *curvature lines are geodesic lines.*  The latter have zero torsion and constant curvature.

However, I must not be understanding the context here.  For instance, consider Monge's ellipsoid (an illustration can be found on page 3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411403v1)).  It seems to me (and in fact, I can confirm via numerical integration) that if I construct a geodesic starting with a tangent to a line of curvature (say, one near an umbilical point), the geodesic will look nothing like the line of curvature.  What gives?

More generally, I am interested in the following question.  For an embedded sphere $S$, consider a connection whose holonomy around any loop equals $2\pi$ times the sum of the indices of the umbilical points enclosed by that loop.  (Here I mean indices in the sense of the principal foliation.)  Are the geodesics defined by this connection lines of principal curvature?  Again, numerical experiments say "yes," but Cartan says "no" — according to the above statements, it would seem that curvature lines are simply geodesic with respect to the *Levi-Civita* connection.

Comment: This is indeed strange, of course curvature lines are almost never geodesics. As for the second question, defining holonomy does not seem to define a connection uniquely. Do you mean any connection with this holonomy or some specific one?


Comment: Ah, yes, sorry --- uniqueness is given by the fact that the connection I'm considering is also closest to the Levi-Civita connection in the sense of the norm induced by the Hodge inner product.

Comment: In which chapter and section of Cartan's is this discussion found? I only have a Russian translation here - page numbers are different.


Comment: In my copy it's in Chapter 24 (Forms of Laguerre and Darboux), Section 152 (Invariance of normal curvature under parallel transport of a vector).

Comment: You might try switching to Ivey, Thomas A.; Landsberg, J.M. (2003), Cartan for Beginners: Differential Geometry via Moving Frames and Exterior Systems, Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 61, American Mathematical Society, ISBN 0-8218-3375-8  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces

Comment: Ivey and Landsberg is a good book, but it doesn't discuss the connection between geodesics and curvature lines that fuzzytron is asking about.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking more of the apparent error, perhaps introduced by one of the translators. My impression is went to Russian first, then English. Plus there may simply be missing context: the Cartan quote would work along the equator of a surface of revolution such as a hyperboloid of revolution of one sheet. 

Comment: Russian translation has a sentence "**We require that** the normal curvature does not change [under parallel transport]" at the beginning of section 152. It is the 3rd sentence after the section title. The rest of the section is about what follows from this assumption.
